# I want to use the values of two cells per line in my formula

Tags: excel

I have a formula as follows

```
=COUNTIF($O$2:$O$746,">=-0.8")-COUNTIF($O$2:$O$746,">-0.78")
```

Where it references =-0.8 and >-0.78 above, these numbers -0.8 and -0.78 are the contents of cells Q2 and S2 respectively. The  value within these cells changes per line so I want to be able to create a formula which will take the value of these cells and use it without having to type in the values for each line as there are over 3000 lines.
Thanks for any help.
Cheers

Comment: any updates on this? if my answer is not ok; just say so in a comment here (or in an edit to your question if you cannot comment); I'll remove my answer if it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add a `$` sign, that value will change. This should do the trick:

```
=COUNTIF($O$2:$O$746,">="$Q2)-COUNTIF($O$2:$O$746,">"$S2)
```

**some explanations:**

```
$O$2
```

means: always take the value from field O2.

```
$02
```

means: keep the `O`fixed, but when copying; the number 2 can be adapted.

Comment: The `$Q2` and `$S2` should be outside of the quotes so that they are treated as a cell reference instead of a string: `,">="&$Q2` and `">"&$S2`